# separating proguard files in android studio windows 10 failing

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, obfuscation

I have created an android project in `Android Studio` on `Mac`. however when i try to create a release `apk` using android studio in `windows 10` it seems like not including the `proguard` files. as the app crashes in run time due to obfuscating of some classes that it should have skipped based on my proguard setup .

Note that this config works very well on Mac environment.

**INITIAL CONFIG:**

```
    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFile 'proguard-eventbus-3.pro'
        proguardFile 'proguard-acra.pro'
        proguardFile 'proguard-glide.pro'
        proguardFile 'proguard-gson.pro'
        proguardFile 'proguard-square-retrofit2.pro'
        proguardFile 'proguard-project-app.pro'
        testProguardFile 'proguard-project-test.pro'
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

I also tried to move all the proguard files in to single folder and tested it and hit the following build error:

**UPDATED CONFIG:**

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles fileTree(dir: "proguard", include: ["*.pro"]).asList().toArray()
            testProguardFile 'proguard-project-test.pro'
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
}
```

**Error:**

[image]

Comment: How about using `proguardFiles fileTree(dir: 'proguard', include: ['*.pro']).asList().toArray()`?

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך please read the second part of the OP. **UPDATED CONFIG**

Comment: You should see from my comment, there is a difference with your updated config. You're using `"`, in my comment it's using `'`

Comment: Have you checked your progaurd rules? You might have to add -dontwarn to warned classes.

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך thanks you were right. if you like please add it as a answer so i can mark it as correct answer. thanks

Comment: Glad it solve your problem. I've add the answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
proguardFiles fileTree(dir: 'proguard', include: ['*.pro']).asList().toArray()
```

Be aware about the usage of `'`